# "at my new work" vs "at my new job"

Tags: word-choice

Which word is it better to use when someone get a new job and they are at it right now?

> I am at my new **job**.
>
> I am at my new **work**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I am at my new job" implies I started a new job, but not necessarily that I'm there right now.  It depends on context.  If spoken during work hours, it probably means that I'm there now.

"I am at my new work" sounds strange, but if spoken by a native speaker, it could mean that I changed my career, or have a new type of work.  Otherwise I'd assume they meant "I am at my new job".

"I am at my new workplace" or "I am here at my new job" might better imply that I'm at my new job right now.